# System very slow while and after login

Tags: performance, login, screensaver

I'm using OS X 10.8.4 on a Mac Mini with 2.3 GHz Core i5 and 8 GB RAM. For security reason I have to lock my computer to screensaver while I leave my seat for a while. I set it up so that password login is required to dismiss screensaver.

However, while I'm login and after login the system is very slow. (at least 30 sec to type the first character for my password). After login for a while it became normal.

I suppose the reason might be that the system is loading everything from hard disk? If so how can I fix that?

Comment: It should take about 2 seconds :). Turn on the Activity monitor and tell us what is it doing. Does that only happens when you lock it?

Comment: Chrome and Adium takes some memory but not that bad... Yes, it only happens when I lock it. After several minutes use it usually back to normal.

Comment: Is the screen on before you start typing? If not, it's possible the computer is going to sleep after a certain amount of time. (and thus your lag is wakeup related)